# How to use template inheritance and components

Tags: c++, templates, inheritance, components

I am trying to use the Component pattern with templates :

```
template <typename ComponentGraphics>
struct Object {

    ComponentGraphics* graphics;
    // there is other components as well

    Object(ComponentGraphics* _graphics) : graphics(_graphics) {};

    void update() {
        graphics->update(this); //Error occure there
    };
};
```

And then I inherit it with a class Player :

```
class Player : public Object<PlayerGraphics> {
    using Object::Object;
public:

    sf::Vector2f position;
};
```

With the PlayerGraphics.h :

```
class Player;
class PlayerGraphics{
public:
    void update(Player* parent);
};
```

PlayerGraphics.cpp :

```
#include "Player.h"

void PlayerGraphics::update(Player* parent) {
    // Process inputs and update parent
}
```

**The actual problem :**
Then I call the *update(Player * parent)* method from *PlayerGraphics* I get the error **can't convert from 'Object< PlayerGraphics > *' to 'Player *'**

For me the problem come from the inheritance, though I can't find what I did wrong.

Comment: It might be helpful to take a closer look at the error message and see, where exactly the error occurred (file + line number). Is it in `void update() {
        graphics->update(this);
    };`?

Comment: Yep error is triggered at *graphics->update(this);* during PlayerGraphics.cpp generation.

Comment: A minimal example that could be cut and pasted into [Compiler Explorer](https://www.godbolt.org) or the like would be helpful.

Comment: try this: static_cast<ComponentGraphics*>(this)->update(this)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot cast a base class to a derived one implicitly. The cast should be explicit.

For example:

```
struct PlayerGraphics {
    using Parent = Player;
    void update(Parent* parent);
};
```

```
template<typename ComponentGraphics>
struct Object {
    void update() {
        using Parent = typename ComponentGraphics::Parent;
        graphics->update(static_cast<Parent*>(this));
    };
};
```

or using type traits:

```
template<typename ComponentGraphics>
struct Traits;

template<>
struct Traits<PlayerGraphics> {
    using Parent = Player;
};
```

```
template<typename ComponentGraphics>
struct Object {
    void update() {
        using Parent = typename Traits<ComponentGraphics>::Parent;
        graphics->update(static_cast<Parent*>(this));
    };
};
```

Note that `ComponentGraphics` is an incomplete type inside `Object`, and its use is limited. For example, you can use `typename ComponentGraphics::Parent` in `update()` body, but not in its signature. Type traits class is needed in the latter case.

Comment: Thanks a lot :). Is using traits more recomended or the two solutions are equals ?

Comment: @Poulpynator, in your particular example `Traits` class is not needed, but this approach is more universal. For example, you can't say `typename ComponentGraphics::Parent func()` for a member function `Object::func()`, but you can say `typename Traits<ComponentGraphics>::Parent func()`.